# StreamBuilder stream not connecting

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, builder

I'm a newbie to flutter and am trying to implement an app using firebase's real time database and a StreamBuilder to contantly show data updating the values shown in the phone's screen.
My problem is that for some reason, the stream will return a data event (snap.hasData = true) only the first time I load and run the main into the emultor, if I hot reload the script, my `StreamBuilder` won't build and the snap.hasData == false. I believe the code is not wrong because as I said before, the connection via the stream is initialized the first time I install and run the app in the emulator

Here's my code, the initSate and build of this screen.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseReference
        .child('growboxs')
        .orderByChild('access')
        .equalTo(widget.user)
        .once()
        .then( (DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      String path2child = snapshot.value.toString();
      path2child =
          'growboxs/' + path2child.substring(1, 18) + '/dashboard';
      reference2Dashboard = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(path2child);
      progressController = AnimationController(
          vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000)); //5s
      isLoading = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return isLoading ?
                 StreamBuilder(
                      stream: reference2Dashboard.onValue,
                      builder: (context, snap) {
                             if (!snap.hasData) {
                                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                             }
                      if (snap.hasData && !snap.hasError &&
                           snap.data.snapshot.value != null) {
                              DataSnapshot snapshot = snap.data.snapshot;
                              doble temperature = snapshot.value['Temperature'].toDouble();
                              /* keeps on getting values and updating Widget*/
                             .
                             .
                             .
                 ) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());//StreamBuilder
 }//build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing `reference2Dashboard` in `initState`, `initState` only runs once your state is created for the first time or after your state is destroyed and has to be created again. Hot Reload doesn't modify your state, so `initState` doesn't run. It will only run again if you do a Hot Restart.

You could use a `FutureBuilder` in your `build` function, passing the result of the `FutureBuilder` to the `StreamBuilder`, not having to use `initState` at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi it's me again, I hope this isn't a bother for you. So I've tried your suggestion but I'm gettin some unsual behaviour. As a future for the FutureBuilder I'm calling a function which returns the DatabaseReference and for its builder, the StreamBuilder, the problem is that my animations get restarted with every stream event.

Comment: It depends on how you set up your animations to start. If you make them start on the `StreamBuilder` `builder` function, then it will restart all the time. You can take a look at the animations functions, as you can see if the animation is playing, if it is, you just don't restart it. Also, you can take a look at implicit animations widgets, sometimes they are more than enough.

Comment: If this answer solved your original question, don't forget to accept and vote for it.